# How to replace nulls in a merge and add

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, merge

I have two Dataframes,

```
DF1
+----+-------+------+------+
|id  | pnl   |value2|value3|
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |10     |20    |30    |
|  2 |20     |30    |40    |
|  3 |30     |40    |50    |
+----+-------+------+------+

DF2
+----+-------+------+------+
|id  | pnl   |value2|value3|
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |100    |200   |300   |
|  2 |200    |300   |400   |
|  3 |300    |400   |500   |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

I am trying to merge these two dataframes by id and add the value columns together. So get something like this.

```
+----+-------+------+------+
|id  | pnl   |value2|value3|
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |100+10 |200+20|300+30|
|  2 |200+20 |300+30|400+40|
|  3 |300+30 |400+40|500+50|
+----+-------+------+------+
```

This works fine when I use

```
// extract the names of the columns to sum
val cols = df1.columns.filter(_!="id") 

// join and sum
val result = df1
    .join(df2,Seq("id"), "full_outer")
    .select( col("id") +: cols.map(c=>df1(c)+df2(c) as c) : _*)
```

But when one id is missing in one of the dataframes. For example

```
DF1
+----+-------+------+------+
|id  | pnl   |value2|value3|
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |10     |20    |30    |
|  2 |20     |30    |40    |
|  3 |30     |40    |50    |
|  4 |40     |40    |40
+----+-------+------+------+

DF2
+----+-------+------+------+
|id  | pnl   |value2|value3|
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |100    |200   |300   |
|  2 |200    |300   |400   |
|  3 |300    |400   |500   |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

I get following values after I merge using the operation I mentioned above.

```
+----+-------+------+------+
|id  | pnl   |value2|value3|
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |100+10 |200+20|300+30|
|  2 |200+20 |300+30|400+40|
|  3 |300+30 |400+40|500+50|
|  4 |null   |null  |null  |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

I understand that I am getting this because I don't have that id in df2. So one way I thought of solving this is by using .na.fill(0.0) after the merge

```
// join and sum
val result = df1
    .join(df2,Seq("id"), "full_outer").na.fill(0.0)
    .select( col("id") +: cols.map(c=>df1(c)+df2(c) as c) : _*)
```

But spark doesn't seem to like that and I get the following error.

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'pnl' is ambiguous, could be: pnl, pnl.;

Anyone know a workaround for this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cols.map(c => coalesce(df1(c), lit(0)) + coalesce(df2(c), lit(0)) as c)`

Comment: Tried it. Can you pass a 0 as a second arg to the coalesce function? It is asking for a column

Comment: Use lit(0) please